# In a certain code 'NATIONAL' is written as 'JUBOKZMN'. How is 'ELECTION' written in that code?

Tags: mathematics, cipher

In a certain code 'NATIONAL' is written as 'JUBOKZMN'. How is 'ELECTION' written in that code?

- (A) FMFDSHNM
- (B) DFMFMNHS
- (C) DMFMFHNS
- (D) MFDFHSMN

I really tried many basic methods using positional values of letters but I failed. Any guess?

I found this puzzle in a highschool level Reasoning and Aptitude Olympiad here in India that was held in the year 2022.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: @fljx Is it ok now?

Comment: If possible, include specific details: What Olympiad?  When?

Comment: @DanielMathias Sure

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with 'NATIONAL'

> Split the word in halves:
>  -- NATI ONAL
>  Increase each letter of the first half:
>  -- OBUJ ONAL
>  Decrease each letter of the second half:
>  -- OBUJ NMZK
>  Reverse the letters in each half:
>  -- JUBO KZMN
>  Result:
>  -- JUBOKZMN

In the same manner, 'ELECTION' becomes

> (B) DFMFMNHS

Comment: That's impressive! But how do you guys come up with these solutions any book to recoommend?